# How to remove a song from Google Play Music without removing it from the storage?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, google-play-music

I recently added a couple of ringtones and notification sounds to my phone by placing them into my storage's Ringtone and Notification directories respectively, and I can select them from the sound settings dialogs without any problem.

The thing is that they also appear as songs on my Google Play Music's playlists, and of course I don't want to hear a 1 second long "jigglypuff!" notification sound every now and then when I'm listening to my music on shuffle.

I did search using Google for a while but it seems that there's no way of either removing the file from just the music database or from excluding those directories from the media search. I recall this didn't happen on an old 4.0 Sony Xperia phone I had with it's music player.

Comment: In which folder did you save your local music on the phone ?

Comment: It's either on the music or the downloads directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello everyone and thank you for your answers, I've finally managed to accomplish this with a very simple solution: The Android media storage service will not index media files inside directories which are hidden (preceded by a "."), but also those which contain a file named ".nomedia", so I just created on all the directories I wanted to exclude and that was it. Hope it helps somebody else.

P.S.

I didn't want to hide the entire directories since they're my phones ringtones and notifications directories and I still want them to be visible to the sound manager to use them, I just don't want them to be seen by Google Play Music.

I found the solution here: http://www.guidingtech.com/15563/hide-certain-files-android-music-player-photo-gallery/

Comment: According to discussions [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37490/how-do-you-prevent-google-music-from-importing-all-mp3-files-on-the-device), the `.nomedia` option may or may not work anymore, and it may or may not require reboots and turning on/off the `Downloaded only` option.

Comment: The `.nomedia` option appears to have worked for me after a reboot.  (I did several other things at the same time, but that's likely to be the minimum it needed.)

Answer (score 0):

I may not be able to help you 100% with this, but I had a similar issue when storing audio books on my SD card. What I did was made a folder called .audiobooks
The . In front made it hidden from Google Play Music. Now, I'm not sure if in your situation this will hide it from the system for ringtones.

Comment: The system is no longer able to find them by using dot directories

Answer (score 0):

See: [How do you prevent Google Music from importing all .mp3 files on the device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37490/how-do-you-prevent-google-music-from-importing-all-mp3-files-on-the-device)

Make the folder hidden by putting a "." In front of the folder name, like:
.audiobooks instead of audiobooks

or make use of the .nomedia files.

Comment: I thought of that too, but I'm wondering wouldn't that make the Ringtone and Notification directories be ignored by the Android under Settings too? I would bet on yes since Mediaserver keeps the databases of all sound files including the Ringtones and notifications used by Android Settings.

Comment: That's right, they won't show on the system's menu now

Answer (score 0):

In case of notification and alarm sounds you can save them in the `Notifications` and `Alarms` folder on you device and they won't show. The folders should already be there.

If it's other audio file Madelin's and user31's answers should be good.

Comment: They're already there, and Play Music still adds them to the library

Answer (score 0):

Placing a '.' in front of a folder prevents google play music from loading songs into the app but prevents you from using the ringtones inside of the hidden folder for default alarms and ringtones.