# How can I exclude Sound Recorder files from Music library

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, google-play-music, voice-recording

I am a fairly new Android user. I am using a Lenovo Vibe K4 Note running Android version 6.0. 
I have **two basic queries** related to each other. My first question is about the Google Play music library (or for any music player app for that matter). The library aggregates all the music files on the phone, including .ogg files created by the Sound Recorder. **I do not want this behavior.** 
I added a .nomedia file to my sound recordings folder as suggested [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37490/how-do-you-prevent-google-music-from-importing-all-mp3-files-on-the-device/117315#117315). On my phone, this folder is located at **Local > Internal Storage > Audio > SoundRecorder**. The Sound recordings were gone from the Google Play app. However, one side effect of this was that the recordings stopped showing in the Sound Recorder app as well. This is an undesired behavior since I happen to use the Recorder app and its easier to see my files there rather than going into the File Explorer. 
**Question 1:** **Is there any way to have the Recordings excluded from Music Apps but not from the Sound Recorder app?** 
My second question is about a related problem I had. While the .nomedia trick worked initially, it randomly stops doing its job i.e. the media starts showing up in all places. At this point, I tried all the suggestions I found such as clearing Media Cache and rebooting the Phone. It does not work and the media still shows. The .nomedia method has been working perfectly for Image files from WhatsApp and Facebook apps which I have blocked from showing up in my Gallery. And that always works, so what is up with Audio files? 
**Question 2:** **Can you provide any information on why .nomedia stops working intermittently and randomly for different file types?**

I am grateful for all answers or links to information to this frustrating issue. Thanks community! First Post Nailed!!!

Comment: See related question, specifically comment of izzy http://android.stackexchange.com/a/130137/131553

Comment: Good. If it works for you, you can self answer the question.  That is fine here

Comment: Done. I would still appreciate any information on Question 2 and why the .nomedia thing isn't reliable in its behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to the first problem thanks to the [reference by beeshyams](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130132/multiple-music-libraries/130137#130137). 
[MortPlayer Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.stohelit.folderplayer) allows you to choose which folders to draw your music from. Hence, in my case, I removed all the .nomedia files from Sound Recorder and only allowed music from my Music folder in MortMusic, thus leaving the SoundRecorder functionality as it was (i.e. recordings show up in the Recorder App) but not in MortMusic, where only my desired .mp3's show.

Comment: There are many music players that offers such features. For a premium experience, I recommend **Poweramp**